# Screen flashes black when open laptop lid

Tags: windows-10, display, lenovo-laptop, lid

Whenever I open laptop lid, the screen quickly turns off and then again turns on. I also noticed that when I open lid then mouse pointer is in a different position.

My settings are "Do nothing" on closing the lid. I have the latest versions of drivers.

I think that video best illustrates this issue.
https://youtu.be/e_bdacFrif0

Addendum: This issue occurs in Windows only. It does not occur in BIOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably Windows re-configuring the display manager based on what displays are available...

If you connect an HDMI / DisplayPort screen, then it will probably *magically* show an output on that display, likely resulting in a dual screen configuration.

If you were then to close the lid of your laptop, the internal display would be seen as 'unavailable', and the system would reconfigure to the single external display.

In the video you can see that your laptop's display is actually *off* when the lid is closed.

Windows has never been very good at flicker-free display configuration...

This also explains the mouse position and why you don't see it in the BIOS - it's a high level 'usability feature' of Windows...

Here's a demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAAdleEsQ7A - 
Unplugging a display would result in similar behaviour, and I think that the mouse moving to top-right is a bug in Windows...

Answer (score -1):

This could be a symptom of your display connection having gotten loose. Hence, when you rotate the lid on its hinges, the connection is momentarily disrupted.

The best course of action would be to take your laptop to an authorized service center. Or, if you have DIY skills, break out your ohmmeter and magnifying glass and investigate the connection.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then the problem also would be occur in the BIOS for example, but there is ok.

Comment: Hmmm... Yes. I think you should add this bit of info to the original message.